# Iteration of mapping with nested iterates in logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product, complex-dynamics

Consider the mapping
$$
g: [0, 1) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \longmapsto g(x) := \frac{x}{1-\ln|x|}
$$
It is easily seen that $g$ is a bijective continuous mapping from $[0, 1)$ onto itself with $g(0) = 0$ well-defined. I'm concerned with the iteration of $g$ with itself, i.e. for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, consider
$$
g^{[0]}(x) := x, \\
g^{[1]}(x) := g(x), \\
g^{[2]}(x) := g(g(x)),\\
\vdots \\
g^{[n]}(x) := g(g(g(\dots g(x) \dots))) \; \; (n \text{ times})
$$
where $g^{[n]}$ denotes the **n-fold iterate** of $g$. Via induction, one can see that

> $$ g^{[n]}(x) = \frac{x}{\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 -\ln\left| g^{[k]}(x) \right| \right)} \tag{1} $$

holds for all $x \in [0,1)$ and all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. In other words, the $n$-fold iterate $g^{[n]}$ can be expressed using the former $k$-fold iterates $g^{[k]}$ for $k = 0, \dots, n-1$. This "*nesting*" of iterates (especially in combination with the logarithm) makes it quite hard for me to analyze the expression in (1), to be honest. Basically, I'm having three questions on this:

1. Is there some theory or concepts on things like *nested mappings* similar to the situation given above? Note that I'm aware of iteration theory in complex analysis (also called complex dynamics), but I'm not able to see how this fits in here...note that $g$ may also be considered as a mapping of the complex unit disk $\mathbb{D} := \{ |z| < 1 \}$ (and its closure) into $\mathbb{C}$, of course.
2. Can anything be said if $n$ tends to infinity, i.e. what "is" $g^{[\infty]}$ if it exists? In other words, does the product in (1) converge in a certain sense (pointwise, [locally] uniformly)?
3. Is there a way of estimating the expression in (1) (with respect to the absolute value)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the purpose of taking the absolute value of $x$ if $0\le x < 1$?

Comment: Indeed, one may omit the absolute value due to the obvious non-negativity. I decided to keep the absolute value, however, since it appears in the original problem that led to the situation described above.

Comment: Iterating any function of the form $g(x) = x \cdot h(x)$ will lead to expressions as in (1): $g(g(x)) = xh(x)h(g(x))$, $g(g(g(x))) = xh(x)h(g(x))h(g(g(x)))$ etc.

Comment: juste a note: before complex dynamics was a thing, real dynamics existed (and still does): you can study the iterations of maps $f: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ and find interesting phenomena. see eg https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~mlyubich/papers/Brin-prize.pdf

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki thanks for the information, I'll check it out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2. Can anything be said if $n$ tends to infinity?

$0 \le g(x) < x$ for all $x \in [0, 1)$, so for fixed $x$,
the sequence $g^{[n]}(x)$ is decreasing and bounded below, and
therefore convergent.

$$
 g(g^{[n]}(x)) = g^{[n+1]}(x)
$$ 
and the continuity of $g$ implies that the limit is a fixed-point
of $g$, so we have
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty } g^{[n]}(x) = 0
$$
pointwise in $[0, 1)$.

And since $g$ is increasing, the convergence is uniform on each
compact interval $[0, r] \subset [0, 1)$:
$$
 0 \le g^{[n]}(x) \le g^{[n]}(r) \to 0 \text{ for } n \to \infty.
$$

The convergence is not uniform on $[0, 1)$ because for every $n$
$$
 \sup \{ g^{[n]}(x) \mid 0 \le x < 1 \}  = \lim_{x \to 1 } g^{[n]}(x) = 1 \, .
$$

---

> 3. Is there a way of estimating the expression in (1)?

A simple estimate would be 
$$
g^{[n]}(x) = \frac{x}{\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 1 -\ln g^{[k]}(x)  \right)} \le
\frac{x}{\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( 2 - g^{[k]}(x)  \right)}
 \le \frac{x}{(2-x)^n} \, ,
$$
using the “well-known” inequality $\ln x \le x-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very helpful! So if I get you right, the convergence $g^{[n]} \to 0$ is locally uniformly in $[0, 1)$, right? But it's certainly not going to be uniformly convergent, due to $g(x) \to 1$ for $x \to 1$, isn't it?

Comment: @ComplexFlo: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your time and your help!

Comment: May I ask one more question on this? Since the sequence $(g^{[n]}(x))_n$ is convergent for $x \in [0,1)$, it is a Cauchy sequence, i.e. for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N = N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|g^{[n]}(x) - g^{[m]}(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $n, m \geq N$. Can we conclude from this that $\sup \limits_{x \in [0,1)} |g^{[n]}(x) - g^{[m]}(x)| \leq \epsilon$ holds, i.e. can we switch to the supremum on $[0,1)$ by replacing "<" with "$\leq$"?

Comment: @ComplexFlo: No, you can't, because the $\epsilon$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Of course, my bad :/ Sorry for that...so there won't be any chance that the sequence *of functions* $(g^{[n]})_n$ of the n-fold iterates of $g$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to the supremum metric, right? Or is there any other possibility? I thought of using Weierstraß' approximation theorem (e.g. with Bernstein polynomials) in order to obain a uniform approximation of each $g^{[n]}$ on $[0,1]$ and then estimate the difference $|g^{[n]} - g^{[m]}|$ using the approximation polynomial of highest degree...

Comment: Of course not, otherwise you would have uniform convergence on the entire interval.

Comment: ....which is certainly not the case! OK thank you very much once again! :)